# What do you call the length of time something is switched on?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, technical

I need to describe a process and I'm currently missing the right word. How do you call the **time** (the duration, not the moment of action) when e.g. a light-switch is set to "passing" i.e. the light is on? I thought about *on time* so even non-native speakers don't struggle with its meaning, on the other hand it sounds clumsy.

Is there a word for this?

Comment: It might help if you told us what the process is. Except for *start time*, I can't think of any generic term.

Comment: @Mick I'm talking about the time an actuator is switched on to do his job. This terminology is used to define the time how long it shall stay on this certain state.

Comment: Operating time? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/operating

Comment: So you're talking about the **length** of time that the switch was on for, the duration, not the clock-time at the instant when it was actually switched?

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes excuse me I've missed that, I'm editing the post

Comment: There isn't a word for this which wouldn't result in the sentence appearing overly contrived.  You should consider rewording the sentence according to what the "something" is and what it's active property is.  e.g. "The amount of time that the lamp is lit".

Comment: @Pete That would be misleading, I'm not looking for a very special case but rather for an abstract version of abritary devices, since they shall be replaceable - so I still believe the example with the light switch is appropriate. If there generally isn't a word for this at all then that's fine too, I'm asking because I'm not a native speaker and thus I don't know all probable technical terms.

Comment: The relevant term would probably depend upon whether the switch turns itself off or is turned off manually. If it turns itself on and off by itself, you might call it the "on cycle" and "off cycle". But you wouldn't use terms like that if it was manually switched on and off.

Comment: Engineers use the term "duty cycle" when describing when and for how long something is switched on and off.  It's often expressed as a ratio or percentage - "Lights in the lobby have a duty cycle of 100%, but those in the individual office suites have a duty cycle that averages 40%".  But you could also say "This device has a duty cycle of 5 hours on, 12 hours off".

Comment: @JohnFeltz as you mentioned a `duty cycle` includes the off time, which is something different

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler term I would suggest [*running*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/running).

The second defintion from Merriam-Webster (linked above):

> the activity of managing or operating something

To use in a sentence: "The light was running for 2 two hours".

---

In general the word [*run*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run) has a multitiude of definitions that bascially boil down to action over time.

Another come phrase although not a single word, would be *run time*. As in, "The current run time for the light is two hours".

Answer (score 0):

For a switch you could say *active*. Other synonyms are *engaged*, *operating* and *functioning*.

For a machine (typically a computer) use *uptime*.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, active, engaged, aso. are no words that could be assigned with a time in my opinion. And uptime is too heavyweight since it is not a system just an actuator, considering a situation with the lightswitch is really appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

...during illumination time ....

Comment: whilst illuminated...